# How to set up app to run in full screen

Tags: java, android

Hello i have one problem i'm creating app that will repeat landscape video as background but i don't know how to set it in full screen. I'm creating app in Android studio. App will have landscape like this>[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this .

**way 1**.set in the manifest

```
<activity
    ...
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
```

**way 2**.set in the java code

```
@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   // add this before setContentView methood ,and after super
   requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 

   getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);  

   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}
```

**way 3**.set in the manifest and set in the style

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<resources> 
    <style name="theme_fullScreen" parent="android:Theme.Black"> 
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    </style> 
</resources>
```

in the manifest

```
<activity android:name=".LoginActivity"
    android:theme="@style/theme_fullScreen"/>
```

**Note**

- change the `android:theme` of the `Activity`.
- set `getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);`

Comment: start using your close vote rights

Comment: How to use it ?Hello @NileshRathod .I've been watching you for a long time .

Comment: I am glad to communicate with you .And I am not angry . You are very good . Sorry for my poor English .@NileshRathod

Comment: enjoy codding **glad to communicate with you** me to

Answer (score 0):

Here you go..

To play the video, create one folder name "raw" under "res" folder. Copy your video under "raw" folder. Please keep video name in small characters. Once done please do below modifications

1. style.xml

   ```
   <!-- Base application theme. -->


   <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
       <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
       <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
       <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
       <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
   </style>

   <style name="AppTheme.FullScreen" parent="AppTheme">
       <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
   </style>
   ```

Note - No need to do any changes in AndroidManifest file.

2. MainActivity.java

   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
       getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       VideoView view = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
       Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.samplevideo);
       view.setVideoURI(uri);
       view.start();

       // To keep video in loop
       view.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
           @Override
           public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
               mp.setLooping(true);
           }
       });
   }
   ```

   }
3. activity_main.xml

   `

   ```
       <VideoView
           android:id="@+id/videoView"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
           tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />

       <TextView
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Hello World!"
           android:textSize="30dp"
           app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"></TextView>

   </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
   ```

`

Note - One thing keep in mind that videoview should be immediate child of parent layout, others views/layout will come after videoview.

Is this what you want?